# I am using dplyr to make a table and I want to get the rounding

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, mutate

I am using dplyr to make a table in R. I want to round to the tenth place so 1.0 or 2.3. I am using the following  code

`mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1)`

This kind of works; most of the rounding looks great except for when it should round and put a zero, like a 1.0 it just shows 1
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this KCS. Voting to close and downvoting because while you told us what you want, you didn't provide a reproducible example. Please update it with a reproducible example and I'll remove those thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the question is more about table presentation and less about storing of rounded values, those are usually separated concepts. If you want to control the format of values in output tables (i.e. with `kable` / `kableExtra`, `gt`, `formattable`, ... or perhaps just `tibble` output), it's formatting and not (just) rounding you might be interested in.

Here's an example of a formatted `tibble` column; also note the last expression that shows how data is stored (`1`, `1.2501` and not `1.0`, `1.3`), meaning that if you do need rounded values in your calculations, you should still round:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble(n = c(1, 1.2, 1.2501, 1234), 
             l = LETTERS[1:4])

# tibble::num -- format a numeric vector
df_rounded <- mutate(df, across(where(is.numeric), \(x) tibble::num(x, digits = 1)))

# how it prints:
df_rounded      
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>           n l    
#>   <num:.1!> <chr>
#> 1       1.0 A    
#> 2       1.2 B    
#> 3       1.3 C    
#> 4    1234.0 D

# how formatted numeric column is represented:
dput(df_rounded$n)
#> structure(c(1, 1.2, 1.2501, 1234), pillar = structure(list(sigfig = NULL, 
#>     digits = 1, label = NULL, scale = NULL, notation = NULL, 
#>     fixed_exponent = NULL, extra_sigfig = NULL), class = c("pillar_num_attr", 
#> "pillar_vctr_attr", "tibble_vec_attr")), class = c("pillar_num", 
#> "pillar_vctr", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>